# What is the best way to model a polarizer?

Tags: density-matrix, photonics

If I have a photon reaching a polarizer, I can think of a polarizer as an operator of  $P=a^\dagger_Va_V$ where $a^\dagger_V$ creates a photon with vertical polarization (V).

However, on the other side this operator destroys my state if there is no vertically polarized photon. This is weird as if I project the polarizer on the density matrix of a state like $\frac1{\sqrt2}(a^\dagger_V+a^\dagger_H)$ (H for horizontal) is

$$P\rho P= \frac{1}{2}a^\dagger_V|\varnothing\rangle\langle\varnothing|a_V$$

but this is weird as I would expect some kind of state of the form:
$$P\rho P= \frac{1}{2}a^\dagger_V|\varnothing\rangle\langle\varnothing|a_V+\frac{1}{2}|\varnothing\rangle\langle\varnothing|$$
indicating that half of the time the state is in the zero photon state. Is the polarizer as defined correct? If the definition is correct, is the polarizer not unitary (is it measuring the state)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polarizer is indeed not unitary: consider that many different input states could have the same output state, such as all states $\alpha|H\rangle+\beta|V\rangle\to|H\rangle$, so the transformation cannot be uniquely reversed and thus it is not unitary.

The correct description of a polarizer is to treat it as a partial trace over one polarization mode. For example, if the polarizer transmits horizontally polarized light and blocks vertically polarized light, one traces over the vertical polarization degree of freedom. Physically, this comes because the vertically polarized light might have actually been reflected and absorbed somewhere, so we are ignoring those photons or removing all information about them or we have completely lost them, so they must be traced out.

We write the basis states in the horizontal-vertical mode decomposition as
$$|m\rangle_H\otimes|n\rangle_V\equiv|m,n\rangle=\frac{a_H^{\dagger m}}{\sqrt{m!}}\frac{a_V^{\dagger n}}{\sqrt{n!}}|\rm{vac}\rangle,$$ where $|\rm{vac}\rangle$ is the two-mode vacuum and the bosonic creation operators commute with each other. A general polarization state is then
$$\rho=\sum_{m,n,m^\prime,n^\prime\geq 0}\rho_{mnm^\prime n^\prime} |m,n\rangle\langle m^\prime,n^\prime|.$$ The action of a polarizer that blocks vertical light is then
$$\rho\to \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\mathbb{I}_H\otimes\langle k|_V) \rho (\mathbb{I}_H\otimes|k\rangle_V)=\sum_{m,m^\prime\geq 0}\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\rho_{mnm^\prime n}\right) |m\rangle\langle m^\prime|.$$ I.e., the new coefficients of the horizontally polarized density matrix in the single-mode Fock basis are $\rho_{mm^\prime}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\rho_{mnm^\prime n}$.

How does this work with the example in question? The initial state is $|\psi\rangle=(a_H^\dagger+a_V^\dagger)|\rm{vac}\rangle/\sqrt{2}=(|1,0\rangle+|0,1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. To compute the partial trace, we will need $$\mathbb{I}_H\otimes\langle k|_V|\psi\rangle=(\delta_{k,0}|1\rangle_H+\delta_{k,1}|0\rangle_H)/\sqrt{2}.$$
Acting on $|\psi\rangle$ with the partial trace, we find that the Kronecker deltas give us the correct result
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\mathbb{I}_H\otimes\langle k|_V) |\psi\rangle\langle \psi| (\mathbb{I}_H\otimes|k\rangle_V)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\delta_{k,0}|1\rangle_H+\delta_{k,1}|0\rangle_H)(\delta_{k,0}\langle 1|_H+\delta_{k,1}\langle 0|_H)/2=(|1\rangle_H\langle 1|+|0\rangle_H\langle 0|)/2$$ as expected.